# Local Host forbidden error and htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent a lot of time and read for the whole day to use htaccess in local host (Ubuntu).

I have folowed below steps.

1) Remove the '#' symbol from the line "AccessFileName .htaccess" File
    : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

2) changed, File : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

to

```
   <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

3) Created a folder at the path /var/www/machine and placed two file index.html and demo.html
created a file .htaccess and the content of it is,

```
DirectoryIndex demo.html index.html
```

So, when I try to open the path localhost/machine it opens 'index.html' instead of "demo.html".

Also, when I have changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All", I got a "you don't have permission to access localhost" error.